# Math equations on black background

Tags: microsoft-office, colors, microsoft-powerpoint, mathjax

I am preparing a PowerPoint presentation and I need to include mathematical notations. I don't think that Microsoft Equation is able to print in white. I can write my equations in MathJax but it doesn't solve my problem, how can I visualize MathJax code in white?

The only solution I can think of is to take a snapshot of the equation (either written in MathJax or with Microsoft Equation) and inverse the color with Photoshop or something similar but 1) it is a pain (I have many equations to write) and 2) it is probably not very complicated but right now I would not be able to inverse the colors on a picture.

What is the best solution? Is there a nice software that would allow me to create math equations in white?

Changing the background color of my PowerPoint presentation will not be considered as a solution :)

Comment: Why not have a black box behind the equation.  It'll accomplish the same thing.

Comment: Thks for your comment. What is a black box? Do you just mean a black square? I am aiming to write the equation in white over a black background. Adding a white square behind the equation would not be a satisfactory solution as it ruins the design of my slides!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[A quick search for mathjax + color](https://www.google.com/search?q=mathjax+color) reveals a bunch of relevant results!

Answer (score 0):

How about taking a snapshot and then inverting the colors?

For example, you can use *MathType* to type your equations, and *Paint* or *Photoshop* to invert the snapshot colors.

You can also use *LaTeX*, which is of course the most sophisticated way.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes I thought about that (see the second paragraph of my question) but I feel (as I said above) that it would be a pain to have to do that for any single equation. I hope something easier and faster would exist, so that I don't have to use 3 different programs and I don't have to be scared to lose image quality at any single step. I have about 50 equations to write on my slides (and will probably have more equations to write down in the future). I didn't know about *MathType* though. I will definitely have a look to this software